# how to create dynamic table row using javascript and how send ajax requestto servlet class

Tags: java, javascript, html

how to create a dynamic table creation using javascript in jsp.

end of each table row save, update button, delete button. when i click on save button. request table row data goes to servlet through ajax calls.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in Advance!!

**EDIT**
Code included

```
function addRow(tableID) { 
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID); 
  var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 
  var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
  element1.type = "text"; 
  element1.name = "txtcompanyname"; 
  element1.id = "companyname"; 
  cell1.appendChild(element1);
```

Comment: Please show some of your code. This would help MUCHO!

Comment: function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.name = "txtcompanyname";
    element1.id = "companyname";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

Answer (score 0):

insert table structure through ajax.
Suppose there are 10 rows in a dynamic table each having update,delete button.
Assign  different names to these buttons for mapping in database(i.e. which row to edit/delete)
each tr tag will contain different form